# Can't get multiple linked select boxes to populate from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, select

Trying to populate the first box on load, the second on a change to the first and the third on a change to the second. Before I added the third and the code to try and get it to work I had the code working but since trying to get the third and the second linked I've had no luck with getting the first to even populate. Any help would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/4a9f8go5/

HTML code:

```
 <select name="leather1" id="leather1"><option disabled="true" selected>-Select Diameter-</option></select>
<select name="leather2" id="leather2"><option disabled="true" selected>-Select Color-</option></select>
<select name="leather3" id="leather3"><option disabled="true" selected>-Select Clasp-</option></select>
```

JQuery code:

```
    var leather12 = [
    {
     "value" : "0",
     "diameter" : "4mm",
     "colors" : ['black','color2','color3'],
     "black" : ['locking','magnetic'],
     "color2" : ['locking2','magnetic2'],
     "color3" : ['locking3','magnetic3']
    },
    {
     "value"   : "1",
     "diameter"   : "4mmd",
     "colors"  : ['black1','color22','color32'],
     "black1"  : ['locking1','magnetic1'],
     "color22"  : ['locking21','magnetic21'],
     "color32"  : ['locking31','magnetic31']
    }
   ] ;

$(function() {
 size2color = [] ;
 for(var i=0; i<leather12.length; i++) {
  size2color[leather12[i].diameter] = leather12[i].colors ;
 }
});

$(function() { 
  color2clasp = [] ;
  for(var i=2; i<leather12[getobjectbyid("leather1").value].length; i++) {
   color2clasp[leather12[getobjectbyid("leather1").value].colors] = leather12[getobjectbyname("leather1").value][this.value][i] ;
  }
});

$(function() {
 // populate diameter select box
 var options = '' ;
 for (var i = 0; i < leather12.length; i++) {
  options += '<option value="' + leather12[i].value + '">' + leather12[i].diameter + '</option>'; 
 }
 $("#leather1").html(options);   // populate select box with array

 // selecting leather1 (change) will populate leather2 select box
 $("#leather1").bind("change",
   function() {
    $("#leather2").children().remove() ;        // clear select box
    var options = '<option disabled="true" selected>-Select Color-</option>' ;
    for (var i = 0; i < size2color[this.value].length; i++) { 
     options += '<option value="' + size2color[this.value][i] + '">' + size2color[this.value][i] + '</option>'; 
    }
    $("#leather2").html(options);   // populate select box with array
   }
 );

 //selecting leather2 (change) will populate leather 2 select box
 $("#leather2").bind("change",
   function() {
    $("#leather3").children().remove();
    var options = '<option disabled="true" selected>-Select Clasp-</option>' ;
    for (var i = 0; i < color2clasp[this.value].length; i++) { 
     options += '<option value="' + color2clasp[this.value][i] + '">' + color2clasp[this.value][i] + '</option>'; 
    }
    $("#leather3").html(options);
   }
 );
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following fiddle :

Your color2clasp was throwing error at getobjectbyid("leather1").value.
Also when a error occurs on one jquery line, lines of code below that are not executed.So the select was not binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/60m5np85/

```
    var leather12 = [
    {
     "value"   : "0",
     "diameter"  : "4mm",
     "colors"  : ['black','color2','color3'],
     "black"  : ['locking','magnetic'],
     "color2"  : ['locking2','magnetic2'],
     "color3"  : ['locking3','magnetic3']
    },
    {
     "value"   : "1",
     "diameter"   : "4mmd",
     "colors"  : ['black1','color22','color32'],
     "black1"  : ['locking1','magnetic1'],
     "color22"  : ['locking21','magnetic21'],
     "color32"  : ['locking31','magnetic31']
    }
   ] ;


$(function() {    

 // populate diameter select box
 var options = '<option disabled="true" selected>-Select Diameter-</option>' ;
 for (var i = 0; i < leather12.length; i++) {
  options += '<option value="' + leather12[i].value + '">' + leather12[i].diameter + '</option>';
 }
 $("#leather1").html(options);   // populate select box with array

 // selecting leather1 (change) will populate leather2 select box
 $("#leather1").bind("change",
   function() {
    $("#leather2").children().remove() ;        // clear select box
    var options = '<option disabled="true" selected>-Select Color-</option>' ;
       var colors = leather12[this.value]["colors"];
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { 
     options += '<option value="' + colors[i] + '">' + colors[i] + '</option>'; 
    }
    $("#leather2").html(options);   // populate select box with array       
   }                                                              
 );

 //selecting leather2 (change) will populate leather 2 select box
 $("#leather2").bind("change",
   function() {

    $("#leather3").children().remove();
    var options = '<option disabled="true" selected>-Select Clasp-</option>' ;
       var clasp = leather12[$("#leather1").val()][$("#leather2").val()];
    for (var i = 0; i < clasp.length; i++) { 
     options += '<option value="' + clasp[i] + '">' + clasp[i] + '</option>'; 
    }
    $("#leather3").html(options);
   }
 );
});
```